# Build a failsafe if sunspot-solr is not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I am currently building a Rails 3.2 application that uses the gem `sunspot` to provide search functionality for my application. `sunspot` uses Apache Solr to perform fulltext indexing and searching.

```
def index
    @search = Article.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      with(:published_at).less_than(Time.zone.now)
      paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
      facet(:published_month)
    end
    @articles = @search.results

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @articles }
    end
end
```

Right now my code just performs a search every time someone hits the article index page and then renders the results. My concern is that `solr` goes down for some reason and my app dies with it. How could I implement a failsafe for this action that performs a basic `Article.all` whenever `solr` goes down?

I know that I could just `rescue` from the exception, but that would still mean that every request generates a connection attempt to `solr`. Is there a way to prevent this? (E.g. catching the exception once and then waiting 5 minutes before the app tries to reconnect to `solr`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a contributor to Sunspot and the cofounder of [Websolr](http://websolr.com), I recommend using `rescue_from` with a low-ish timeout.

Where Sunspot is concerned, it looks like the option to specify a timeout was [recently added](https://github.com/mwmitchell/rsolr/commit/0b7e1767dd43eb07bbe2d247094920c3f734399f) to RSolr, the library Sunspot uses, so if this is a feature you need then you should look into contributing a pull request to Sunspot to pass a timeout to RSolr.

Generating a failing request to Solr shouldn't be that expensive if you have proper timeouts in place. If Solr is down, you want it to be timing out on opening the TCP connection. A healthy Solr server *should* open a TCP connection in an order of magnitude less than a second, and start sending data back in no more than a second or two for really expensive queries.

An open timeout of 0.1 seconds and data timeout of 5 seconds should be more than enough here.

The next best option here is to have some other local proxy between your application and Solr which can throttle requests when Solr is down. Perhaps a caching middleware, or Varnish. Certainly I'd see that as a more complicated approach, unless such a proxy or cache is already a part of your application's infrastructure.

Comment: Well explained and helps a lot! Thanks.

Comment: I was just about to fork `sunspot` to allow setting the timeouts but then I spotted this commit: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/commit/abc3b472c917cea50e6e5ace813a4d13ad1ac08a
So it's already implemented. Nice!